# Custom Menu inside ListView (with Play Store Example)

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I want to mimic what Google is doing here in the Play Store; notice the menu when the overflow button is clicked:

[image]

If you click on the overflow button in each card, what looks like a `ContextMenu` shows up.  Though it shows up right next to the appropriate card that was clicked -- not in the middle of the screen like a regular `ContextMenu`.  Is this in fact a `ContextMenu` or something different?